# juju with MAAS error: file 'provider-state' not found

Tags: juju, maas

I'm trying to configure juju to work w/ MAAS. I'm configuring juju to run on the same node as MAAS. When I run "juju status" I get the following error:

`error: file 'provider-state' not found`

Any thoughts?

Here are the relevant parts from my .juju/environments.yaml:

```
maas:
  type: maas
  # Change this to where your MAAS server lives.  It must specify the base path.
  maas-server: 'http://<server IP>/MAAS/'
  maas-oauth: '<key from MAAS preferences page>'
  admin-secret: 'nothing'
  default-series: precise
  authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Maybe related (link provided by user [gray13](http://askubuntu.com/users/575812/gray13)): [Unable to list controllers with Juju 2.0-beta1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743710/unable-to-list-controllers-with-juju-2-0-beta1)

Answer (score 2):

While I have not seen that error before, I'm thinking that it might be related to the fact that you don't have a bootstrapped environment.

Did you:

```
juju bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered same issue at juju2.0 beta version
and follow this fix it successfully

[Unable to list controllers with Juju 2.0-beta1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743710/unable-to-list-controllers-with-juju-2-0-beta1)

it is an old post but hope it still can help.

Comment: Instead of only linking another Ask Ubuntu question in your answer, you should have flagged this question as duplicate of the other instead. Alternatively, if you think it's not an exact duplicate, you should have left a comment once you have enough reputation.