# Unable to list controllers with Juju 2.0-beta1

Tags: juju, maas

juju version 2.0-beta1-trusty-amd64

juju list-controllers 
CONTROLLER MODEL USER SERVER

Why it is not listing any controllers. I have created a maas environment using quickstart -i. environments.yaml is also created as below.

I tried to switch the environment but getting the error. Here is the yaml file placed at `/root/.juju/environments.yaml`

```
default: maas 
environments: 
maas: 
default-series: trusty 
maas-oauth: <key pasted here from the maas GUI>
maas-server: http://192.168.6.11/MAAS 
type: maas
```

When try to add a cloud using juju add-cloud its also giving the error:

```
error: Usage: juju add-cloud
```

where is the cloud.yaml file ? I have also tried:

```
juju add-cloud maas envoirnments.yaml 
ERROR open envoirnments.yaml: no such file or directory
```

but still no luck.

Can someone please mention the exact steps to setup juju2/MAAS? it appears juju2 has made some major changes. Bootstrapping is also not as it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a new file; cloud.yaml is an arbitrary file name, and you can put it anywhere. The contents should look like this:

```
clouds:
  my-maas:
    type: maas
    auth-types: [oauth1]
    endpoint: http://192.168.6.11/MAAS/
```

Then run `juju add-cloud my-maas <path/to/your/cloud-yaml/file>` to add the cloud to Juju.

You'll then need to add a credential for this by editing ~/.local/share/juju/credentials.yaml, so it contains:

```
credentials:
  my-maas:
    maas:
      auth-type: oauth1
      maas-oauth: <API token from MAAS>
```

In 2.0.0-beta2, you'll be able to add credentials interactively using "juju add-credential". You won't be expected to edit the credentials file directly.

Once you've got those two files set up, you should then be able to run:

`juju bootstrap <controller-name> my-maas`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot. It worked for me. Here are my files settings and few more questions to proceed:

cloud.yaml file

```
clouds:
  maas:
   type: maas
   auth-types: [oauth1]
   endpoint: http://192.168.6.11/MAAS
```

and ~/.local/share/juju/credentials.yaml file.

```
 credentials:
      maas:
        maas:
          auth-type: oauth1
          maas-oauth: <API KEY copied from MAAS>
```

It created a controller named as maas and cloud name also maas.

```
root@maas61:~# juju list-controllers 
CONTROLLER  MODEL  USER         SERVER
maas*       maas   admin@local  192.168.6.193:17070

root@maas61:~# juju list-models 
NAME  OWNER        LAST CONNECTION
maas  admin@local  just now
```

To access the ssh of the bootstrapped node I used this command:

```
juju ssh ubuntu@192.168.6.193 (.193 is the IP of the bootstrapped node)

ubuntu@node0:~$ whoami
ubuntu
```

Now I have 3 questions here.

1- I have 4 nodes in my MAAS setup. Why it picked the node0 to bootstrap. Is there any way we can choose among these or pass the node details ourself ? Please tell the command to configure some other node lets say nodex as boot strap. Currently it appears to pick the first node in the list to bootstrap by default.

2- Can we boot strap multiple nodes for redundancy ? If yes How ?

3- If I want to su to root user in node0 after login as ubuntu how I can do that?

ubuntu@node0:~$ su
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
ubuntu@node0:~$

Is there any way to get root level access  of the bootstraped node??
If I want to access the node0 from some other system which does not have juju installed how can I do that ?

Comment: Please create separate questions (not as an answer to a question), so they're not missed, and so they're more easily discovered by others seeking the same answers.